# Function returns undefined values using pythons module multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

So I try to parallelize the computation of a number of files with the python module multiprocessing.

Below I show a condensed version of my python script. I tried to only keep stuff that I see relevant for the problem. So this is not a working script but should illustrate my usage of the module.

After I run the script and later loop over the list `RESULTS` I get a few items which I can not get my head around.

The list `RESULTS` should be a list containing only lists. Each list represents a result from the computation of one line. They should always look like so `[i, file_name, result]`. Yet there are elements in the list `RESULTS`, that are not of that structure and I don't understand how this is possible given my script.

There are 3 types of structure, some elements have that do not comply with my expected structure.

1. The element is simply `None`
2. The element is an empty list `[]`
3. The element is a list only containing the result but not the `i` and the `file_name`. Hence look like this `[result]` instead of `[i, file_name, result]`

So in essence I can not understand how the function `crunch_line()` can return any of these results.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import json
import os
import subprocess
import gzip
import multiprocessing
import traceback


NUM_CPUS = 25
RESULTS = []


def some_systemcall(line):
    call_list = ["program", line]
    p = subprocess.Popen(call_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    p.wait()
    if p.returncode != 0:
        raise SystemError("program Error:\n" +
                          p.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8'))
    else:
        res = p.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8')
        if res == "":
            return "no result"
        else:
            return res


def crunch_line(i, file_name, line):
    '''Process a single line'''
    try:
        # stuff
        res = some_systemcall(line)
        return [i, file_name, res]
    except:
        return [i, file_name, traceback.format_exc()]


def log_result(result):
    RESULTS.append(result)


def compute_files():
    global RESULTS
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(NUM_CPUS)
    syndicate = []
    for file_name in os.listdir("./some_dir"):
        i = 0
        with gzip.open(f"./some_dir/{file_name}.gz", "rb") as file_handle:
            for line in file_handle:
                line = line.decode("UTF8")
                if line[0] == "#":
                    continue
                i += 1
                syndicate.append(pool.apply_async(crunch_line,
                                                  [i, file_name, line],
                                                  callback=log_result))
        print("Worker queued")
        [worker.wait() for worker in syndicate]
        print("Pool finished")
        result_file_path = f"./some_dir/{file_name}_results.json"
        with open(result_file_path, "w") as file_handle:
            json.dump(RESULTS, file_handle)
        RESULTS = []
        syndicate = []

    pool.close()
    pool.join()


def main():
    compute_files()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```